# Intro java homework

Tags: java, if-statement, random, for-loop

**Instructions for my assignment:** http://media.orvsd.org/FLVS/backup-ap_computer_science_a_v9_gs_-20120821-1900/course_files/flvs/educator_apcsa_v9_gs/module05/rtfmod05/5.06_AssignmentInstructionsBottleCapPrize.pdf

Basically, i have to do 1000 trials. Each trial is when I successfully pick the "bottle cap with the prize". So each time I get that prize I also have to see how many bottle caps I went through before I got that prize in that one trial. What I'm supposed to output in the end is how many bottle caps on average I had to go through to find the prize cap.

I'm having trouble getting that average number of bottles in my program and that's what I need help with. My average doesn't come out correct in the end. As for the input and output of the file, that's part of the assignment and I'v figured that out already so I don't need help there. One more thing, the first two outputFile.println lines of code are just to test to see that the program is working.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class BottleCapPrize
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new File("MonteCarlo.txt"));
    Random randNum = new Random();
    int bottleCapNumber = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    int capsOpened = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        bottleCapNumber = randNum.nextInt(5);
        while(bottleCapNumber != 0)
        {
        bottleCapNumber = randNum.nextInt(5);
        capsOpened++;
        }
        if(bottleCapNumber == 0)
        {
            capsOpened++;
            wins++;
        }
    }
    outputFile.println(capsOpened);
    outputFile.println(wins);
    int averageNumberOfBottles = (int)(((double)wins / (double)capsOpened) * 10);
    outputFile.println("The average amount of bottles that need to be opened are: " + averageNumberOfBottles);    
    outputFile.close();


    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("MonteCarlo.txt"));
    while(inputFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        String token = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(token);
    }
        inputFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: My average doesn't come out correctly in the end.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the average by 10?  Also, you may wish to look into using more methods, to make them smaller and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating caps opened per win so **average formula is wrong** It should be

```
 int averageNumberOfBottles = (capsOpened / wins);
```

Answer (score 2):

While it might not be the root of the problem, it seems to me that

```
while (bottleCapNumber != 0) {
    bottleCapNumber = randNum.nextInt(5);
    capsOpened++;
}
if (bottleCapNumber == 0) {
    capsOpened++;
    wins++;
}
```

Could be rewritten in a more direct, *clear* manner.  Since at the end of the *while* statement, `bottleCapNumber` **must** equal `0` (otherwise, you'll still be looping in the while statement), it could be rewritten.

```
while (bottleCapNumber != 0) {
    bottleCapNumber = randNum.nextInt(5);
    capsOpened++;
}
capsOpened++;
wins++;
```

Which due to the associative property of addition, could easily be rearranged

```
capsOpened++;
while (bottleCapNumber != 0) {
    bottleCapNumber = randNum.nextInt(5);
    capsOpened++;
}
wins++;
```

Which makes it obvious you are using a 1-based numbering routine for `capsOpened`.

As far as the division to figure out the average, as others have pointed out, you are forcing *integer* division, which means that you will not produce a non-integer output (results will only be the number of times the division is cleanly possible).  This will dramatically change the answer.

What you need is

```
 double averageNumberOfBottles = ((double)capsOpened / wins);
```

Note that `double` cast of `capsOpened`.  This forces `capsOpened` to be handled as a real value instead of an integer value.  Since `capsOpened` is now being handled as a real number, the division by an integer will also yield a real number.  Naturally you need a real variable to hold the result, so you don't chop off the digits.

It is also not clear to me why you decided to divide `wins/capsOpened` as that would give you the average number of wins per opened cap.  I thought you wanted the average number of opened caps per win.  The introduction of a wild "and then multiply that by 10" might be a left-over in trying to figure out what was going wrong, but you certainly don't want 10 times the correct answer.

One last sideline.  While `java.util.Random` is an "ok" random number generator, it isn't as Random as a few other options.  Sure it is built in, and returns numbers pretty quickly; but, if you really want a better (slower) source of random numbers, use `java.secure.SecureRandom`.  In my tests I typically got back

```
with java.util.Random : 
4.696
4.948
4.766
4.901
4.832

with java.secure.SecureRandom : 
4.929
5.058
5.065
4.932
4.782
```

which isn't enough runs to determine a statical significance in the difference of the outputs, but it certainly suggests that `java.util.Random` is less random than `java.secure.SecureRandom` if `java.util.Random` rarely crosses the 5.0 mark.